# Grocery crud error inserting row

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

Im using grocery crud 1.5.7.
Im using it without problems for some time.

This is my code:

```
 $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_subject('Detalle Oferta');
    $crud->set_table('oferta_detalle');

    $crud->columns('id_oferta','id_articulo','cantidad');
    $crud->add_fields('id_oferta','id_articulo','cantidad');
    $crud->edit_fields('id_oferta','id_articulo','cantidad');
    $crud->required_fields('id_oferta','id_articulo','cantidad');



    $crud->unset_delete();
    $crud->field_type('cantidad', 'integer');

    $crud->display_as('id_oferta','Nro. Oferta');
    $crud->display_as('id_articulo','Articulo');



$crud->set_relation('id_articulo','articulo','descripcion');
    $crud->set_relation('id_oferta','oferta','{id_oferta} - {fecha_vencimiento}');


    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
```

The insert is completed in database but the result on screen is:

{"success":true,"insert_primary_key":7,"success_message":"
Sus datos han sido guardados correctamente. Editar Detalle Oferta</a> o Volver a la lista</a></p>","success_list_url":"http://compras.esamap.info/site/index.php/proveedores/detalle_ofertas/index/success/7"}

When I don use set_relation I dont get error, but I need set_relation ...
Anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled grocery crud and codeigniter and worked fine.
I think was an incompatibility of versions.

Thanks a lot!